# From an R dataframe: count non-NA values by column, grouped by one of the columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I guarantee there is a simpler way to accomplish my goal.  I need to count the non-NA values of a data frame, grouped by one column in said data frame.  *This is my first question on stackoverflow, please be patient with me.

Here is my current code:

test data:

```
grouping <- c(1234,5678,2359)
column1 <- c('asdf',NA,NA)
column2 <- c(NA,'asdf','asdf')
column3 <- c('asdf',NA,'asdf')
litmus <- data.frame(grouping, column1, column2, column3)
```

get distinct list of groups:

```
distinct_groups <- as.data.frame(litmus %>% distinct(grouping))
length(distinct_groups$grouping)
```

perform loop to count non-NA values by grouping and put into a list

```
count_non_NA = list()
for (i in 1:length(distinct_groups$grouping)){
  count_non_NA[[i]]<-apply(litmus[grouping == as.numeric(distinct_groups$grouping[i]),], 2, function(x) length(which(!is.na(x))))}
```

input group names into list and convert to dataframe

```
names(count_non_NA) <- distinct_groups$grouping
count_non_NA <- as.data.frame(count_non_NA)
count_non_NA
```

Comment: I pulled this together using the aggregate function in stats. `aggregate(litmus, by = list(groupingnonNA = grouping), FUN = function(x){sum(!is.na(x))})` I'm not sure if this fits with your desired output so didn't submit as an answer, but hopefully you can edit to meet requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `summarise_all`

```
library(dplyr)
litmus %>% 
   group_by(grouping) %>% 
   summarise_all(funs(sum(!is.na(.))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a few extra observations so you can see how the grouping works as the example you provided there is only 1 observation per group.

```
library(dplyr)

grouping <- c(1234,5678,2359, 1234,5678,2359)
column1 <- c('asdf',NA,NA, 'asdf',NA,NA)
column2 <- c(NA,'asdf','asdf', NA,'asdf','asdf')
column3 <- c('asdf',NA,'asdf', 'asdf',NA,'asdf')
litmus <- data.frame(grouping, column1, column2, column3)

litmus %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(grouping) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise_at(vars(column1:column3), ~ sum(!(is.na(.))))

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   grouping column1 column2 column3
#   <dbl>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#   1234       2       0       2
#   2359       0       2       2
#   5678       0       2       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be simply 
`sum(!is.na(column name))` for each vector...

For a data frame using dplyr:

```
df%>%group_by(grouping_variable)%>%summarise("nonNAcol1"= sum(!is.na(col1name),
```

.....so on.for other columns)

There could more general solutions using apply functions on columns or seq_along columns for unknown number. Check SO for more and dplyr tutorials. 
R4ds chapter 5.. http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html

Cheers.

Comment: Just search for entries on na.omit or count NA values...for more variety.